# project with tgbot-cpp doesnt build?

Tags: c++, windows, telegram-bot, clion

I'm encountering linker errors while trying to build my C++ project on Windows using CMake. The project uses the tgbot-cpp library for Telegram bot development. Despite trying various solutions, I haven't been able to resolve these errors.

Here's a snippet of my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(todolistbot)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL)
include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
if (CURL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_CURL)
endif()
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DTGBOT_DISABLE_NAGLES_ALGORITHM -DTGBOT_CHANGE_SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE -DTGBOT_CHANGE_READ_BUFFER_SIZE")

add_executable(todolistbot main.cpp
        keyboards.h)

# Link against Boost.Asio, OpenSSL, Threads, CURL, and ws2_32 library
target_link_libraries(todolistbot
        PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
        ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        ${CURL_LIBRARIES}
        ws2_32
        C:/Users/menshutkin/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/TgBot.lib)
```

And here's a sample of the linker errors I'm encountering:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/todolistbot.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `operator()':
D:/C++_pj/todolistbot/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `TgBot::Api::sendMessage(boost::variant<long long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, int, std::shared_ptr<TgBot::GenericReply>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TgBot::MessageEntity>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<TgBot::MessageEntity> > > const&, bool, bool, int) const'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: D:/C++_pj/todolistbot/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `StringTools::startsWith(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: D:/C++_pj/todolistbot/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `TgBot::Api::sendMessage(boost::variant<long long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, int, std::shared_ptr<TgBot::GenericReply>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TgBot::MessageEntity>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<TgBot::MessageEntity> > > const&, bool, bool, int) const'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/todolistbot.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `main':
D:/C++_pj/todolistbot/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `TgBot::Bot::_getDefaultHttpClient()'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: D:/C++_pj/todolistbot/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `TgBot::Bot::Bot(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, TgBot::HttpClient const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: D:/C++_pj/todolistbot/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `TgBot::Api::getMe() const'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: D:/C++_pj/todolistbot/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `TgBot::TgLongPoll::TgLongPoll(TgBot::Bot const&, int, int, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.2.2\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: D:/C++_pj/todolistbot/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `TgBot::TgLongPoll::start()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've checked my library linking, ensured the library is properly installed via vcpkg, verified the library path, and set the correct include directories. Despite these efforts, I'm still facing these linker errors.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!